# Response.Redirect - How-To

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm trying to figure out how to use the "Response.Redirect" in ASP.NET VB to take two columns from a gridview and if possible from a drop down on the same page and send it to labels on the next page. Is this possible?

Also i'm a tad stuck on understanding where it says "Room & Name". Where do I locate the correct inputs for these? Thank you for any help.

**Updated:**

```
    Protected Sub GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles GridView1.SelectedIndexChanged

    Response.Redirect("RoundingEntry.aspx?Room=" & GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells(1).Text & "&Name=" & GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells(2).Text & "&Rounder=" & DDRounder.SelectedValue)

    End Sub
```

On my next/receiving page i have this...

```
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Me.Page.PreviousPage IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim rowIndex As Integer = Integer.Parse(Request.QueryString("RowIndex"))
        Dim GridView1 As GridView = DirectCast(Me.Page.PreviousPage.FindControl("GridView1"), GridView)
        Dim row As GridViewRow = GridView1.Rows(rowIndex)

        Dim room As String = Request.QueryString("Room")
        Dim name As String = Request.QueryString("Name")
        Dim Rounder As String = Request.QueryString("Rounder")
        lblRoom.Text = room
        lblPatientName.Text = name
        lblRounder.Text = Rounder

    End If
End Sub
```

Source Code for lblRoom.Text

```
<asp:Label ID="lblRoom" runat="server" BackColor="White" Height="22px" 
     Width="100px" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="Inset" BorderWidth="1pt" 
     style="text-align: center; background-color: #CCCCCC;"></asp:Label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Server.Transfer("page.aspx")` if you want the values from controls on the previous page.

If you pass via `querystring`, use `Request.QueryString("Room")` & `Request.QueryString("Name")`

Take a look at this [`article`](http://geekswithblogs.net/ranganh/archive/2005/04/25/37633.aspx) too

You are missing RowIndex here...

```
Response.Redirect("RoundingEntry.aspx?Room=" & GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells(2).Text & "&Name=" & GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells(3).Text "&RowIndex=?")
```

And then in the next page...

```
Dim rowIndex As Integer = Integer.Parse(Request.QueryString("RowIndex"))
Dim room As String = Request.QueryString("Room")
Dim name As String = Request.QueryString("Name")
lblRoom.Text = room 
lblName.Text = name
```

Comment: Sorry, I didnt think i did vote down for yours. I'm trying to use the code you gave me in my page load. How do I then do the response.redirect part for the 2 gridfields and a ddl?        'lblRoom.Text = Request.QueryString("Room")
            lblName.Text = Request.QueryString("Name")
            lblRounder.Text = Request.QueryString("Rounder")'

Comment: (please see my updated post above) I have the two gridview fields plus the dropdown list coming into the Dim statements on the recieving page but when calling on the (lblroom.text = room) its showing "nothing".

Comment: Can you paste your formed url? should look like `RoundingEntry.aspx?Room=roomname&Name=name&Rounder=rounderval`

Comment: Where is this located within debugging? Thanks

Comment: it should be in the url, as in the address bar of your browser.

Comment: I've figured it out and it works currently which is great.  I put in the following in the page load and it works. Thank you for all your help. Appreciated!              If Request.QueryString.Count > 0 Then
            lblRoom.Text = Request.QueryString("Room")
            lblPatientName.Text = Request.QueryString("Name")
            lblRounder.Text = Request.QueryString("Rounder")
        End If